# Doctrine SQL Self Join not returning all data in PHP

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, self-join

I needed to do a self join on a table and since I couldn't do by DQL, I went for SQL. Here's the query:

```
select child.*, parent.* from gamme child
              left join gamme parent on child.gamme_parent = parent.gamme_id
              where child.gamme_catalogue_id = {an id}
```

When I run that query in TOAD, I got the results that I was expecting:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  column_a  |   column_b  |  column_c  | column_a_1 | column_b_1 | column_c_1 |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|            |             |            |            |            |            |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Now, when I try to `var_dump` the same query in PHP, I'm not getting any of the join data:

Here's my php code:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$connection = $em ->getConnection();

$query = "select child.*, parent.* from gamme child
          left join gamme parent on child.gamme_parent = parent.gamme_id
          where child.gamme_catalogue_id =".$catId;

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

That's what the `var_dump` gives me:

```
array
  0 =>
    array (size=3)
      'column_a' => {some values}
      'column_b' => {some values}
      'column_c' => {some values}
  1 =>
    array (size=3)
      'column_a' => {some values}
      'column_b' => {some values}
      'column_c' => {some values}
...
```

How can I get the join data too in PHP?

**EDIT**

Since I could not figure out why I was not getting the join data with SQL, I finally managed to make it work with DQL itself.

Here's how I did it for those who may be looking for a solution on Doctrine entity self join:

```
$qb = $this
        ->_em
        ->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
    ->select('c', 'g', 'p')
    ->from('CatalogueBundle:Catalogue', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.gammes', 'g')
    //"gammes" is found in entity "Catalogue" and targets entity "Gamme" 
    ->leftJoin('g.parent', 'p')
    //"parent" is found in entity "Gamme" and targets entity "Gamme" itself
    ->where('c.catalogueId =:catId')
    ->setParameter('catId', $catId);

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: What is the result of `print_r($query)`?

Comment: @ReynierPM I finally got it working in DQL. I'm gonna edit the question

Comment: cool, glad you get it working!